# App Setup Policy for Custom Teams App does not trigger OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have a Custom Teams App consisting of a notification bot in the personal scope. To distribute it in the organization, we configured an App Setup Policy that installs our app and pins it to the Teams app bar.

So far, so good. When a user that is affected by the App Setup Policy opens teams, he/she sees our pinned app in the app bar, so the policy has taken effect. However, we can observe that the `OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync` method of our bot implementation is not called. Also, the conversation with the Bot does not show up in chats.

When the user clicks on the pinned app in the app bar, `OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync` is eventually called and the user receives a proactive message. The conversation shows up in chats.

This is unfortunate since we would like to proactively messages users without them having to click once on the app first.

I guess the problem is that the conversation of the Bot with the user is not created until the user clicks on the App. Is there a way for Teams Administrators to make sure that the conversation is started with all the users in the organization and proactive messages can be sent?

Answer (score 1):

The way via App Setup Policy does not work as it does not really install the app.

However, in can be done quite easily via a Powershell script and using the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation). Here's a script that solves the problem:

```ps
<#
 .SYNOPSIS
    Installs the a Teams app for all members of an Azure AD group

 .DESCRIPTION
    Follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation to install & setup the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK.

    To run, a Global Admin account is required.

    The script gets the transitive members of the provided AAD group. For each member it checks if the user has the Teams app installed. If not, it installs the app.

.PARAMETER teamsAppId
    The id of the Teams app that should be ensured

 .PARAMETER groupId
    The id of the Azure AD group that should be used to ensure the Teams app for its members
#>

param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string]
    $teamsAppId,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string]
    $groupId
)

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "GroupMember.Read.All", "TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteForUser"

$users = Get-MgGroupTransitiveMember -GroupId $groupId -All

Write-Host "Processing" $users.Count "users"

foreach ($user in $users) {
    if ($user.AdditionalProperties["@odata.type"] -ne "#microsoft.graph.user") {
        continue
    }

    $userId = $user.Id
    $app = Get-MgUserTeamworkInstalledApp -UserId $userId -ExpandProperty "teamsAppDefinition" -Filter "teamsAppDefinition/teamsAppId eq '$teamsAppId'"
    if ($null -eq $app) {
        $params = @{ "TeamsApp@odata.bind" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/$teamsAppId" }
        New-MgUserTeamworkInstalledApp -UserId $userId -BodyParameter $params

        Write-Host "Installed app for user '$userId'" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "User '$userId' has app already installed" -ForegroundColor DarkBlue
    }
}
```

Use it: `.\ensure-teams-app.ps1 -teamsAppId TEAMS_APP_ID -groupId GROUP_ID`